# How to remove delete icon in one2many tree view

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Please advice me on this.need to remove delete icon.but need to create and edit records.
if i set it as readonly then unable to edit also.so what is the better way to implement this

[image: delete icon]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `delete="false"` in `tree` tag.

```
<tree string="My Tree" delete="false">
```

This will remove delete option from `one2many` tree view.

Comment: hey in my case it's not working. I m doing it for many2many. Can u suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I used it also in a form. like that,

```
<form string="Employee" version="7.0" create="false" edit="false" delete="false">
```

it worked.